# Requests in different format HTTP POST to CURL

Tags: javascript, python, curl, post, http-post

I am new to API integration so I need some help in connecting and testing endpoint.can anyone help me to convert this HTTP post in CURL ? or any different way to write a program with it in python or in js.

```
POST URL:
https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token
Headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
Data:
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-
xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-
yyyyyyyyyyyy&redirect_uri=http://www.hubspot.com/&code=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-
zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Answer (score 1):

Curl request would be:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" -X POST -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy&redirect_uri=http://www.hubspot.com/&code=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz' https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token
```

Comment: how to convert this into URL and use in chrome browser in link tab.

Comment: @DinuDuke You cannot convert a POST request into an URL (which is a GET request), however you can use the Developer Console or Postman to create a POST request in Chrome